# Is there a way to rewrite this URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite URLs from:

```
www.example.com/John.Connor/my-first-post/42
```

to:

```
www.example.com/post.php?postid=42&userid=19
```

Tables:

```
USER:
id, name, surname, email, password

POST:
id, title, post, userid
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want it the other way around?

Comment: sorry, yes I want it the other way around. I have just correct :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well mod_rewrite cannot query your database hence it cannot be completely done via .htaccess itself. What you can do is to have this rule in .htaccess:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?postid=42 [L,QSA]
```

Then inside your `post.php` script have code like this:

```
$postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['postid']); 
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userid']);

if (empty($userid)) {
   $userid = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM POST WHERE id=$posid"), 
              0, "userid");
   // now redirect by appending &userid=49 in the current URL
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "&userid=" . $userid);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, but if htaccess cannot query databases, then how can sites like pinterest has URLs like this: http://pinterest.com/robingood/wow-collection/ ( robingood is the username and wow-collection is the category ) ?

Comment: @xRobot: Even SO has such URL scheme. e.g. this question has this URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992072/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-this-url/10996636` Now try entering this short URL for same question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992072` and you will notice it being redirected to former URL. Reason is that it pulls question title from a database and appends it in shorter URL to make it SEO friendly.

Comment: In this case there is question's id ( 10992072 ), but in the pinterest's case there isn't.

Comment: True and that's why SO has better SEO URL than pinterest since it will be faster to lookup ID rather than a long text. Irrespective of ID or no ID both sites are using some sever side code to lookup from a database. (as I have outlined in my answer)